# Copying ISim results as strings/text

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm creating a VHDL project, and using ISim to simulate beforehand - which is all fine.

However, my results use fixed point - and although Isim can represent its signals as a range of radix's, unsurprisingly, fixed point decimal isn't one of them.

Hence I'd like to get the current value of each signal as text but the "copy" function only copies the entity and signal name, and not the string value.

For example

[image]

I want to get the value of "[00010000, 00020000...etc etc] but I actually just get the value of "/fixedpointtb/UUT/s1_fcs[0]" i.e. entity name.

Common sense says there must be a simple way of doing this but I can't see how!

Comment: Through pure luck, I've found I can print the binary strings to the ISim console using the command `show value signal_name` - although this prints the signal as binary only. If anybody has a permutation that allows the signal to be printed to the console as hex, that would be an ideal answer!

Comment: Is it a top-level signal in the testbench? Do you want to print the last state of a signal or at some point in time in your simulation?

Comment: I'm looking to print the signal at that instance in time i.e. the value shown next to the signal diagram. It is a top level signal.

Comment: VHDL has file I/O capabilities. So you could write your signal data (formatted by a custom function) to STDOUT or into a file. E.g. one value per line and time event. If this is in your interested, I could assemble a short example into an answer.

Comment: @Paebbels that sounds great - I would love a quick example I could use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VHDL's file I/O capabilities in your testbench (at top-level) to convert the signals from DUT into a human readable string and write it to STDOUT or into a file.

**A coarse overview on file I/O.**

VHDL has several packages and procedures/functions for file I/O and string operations.

- **std.textio**
  VHDL defines an access type (a pointer) called `line` for `string` and a basic file type `text` for text files.

  Usage:

  ```
  use std.textio.all;
  ```

  Declarations from `std.textio`:

  ```
  -- types
  type line is access string;
  type text is file of string;
  -- STD files
  file input  : text open read_mode  is "STD_INPUT";
  file output : text open write_mode is "STD_OUTPUT";
  -- procedures (some with overloads)
  read      (<lineVar>, <vhdlObji [,<status>]);
  readline  (<fileObj>, <lineVari);
  write     (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,right|left, <width>]);
  write     (<lineVar>, <realObj> [,right|left, <width>, <digits>]);
  write     (<lineVar>, <timeObj> [,right|left, <width>, <unit>]);
  writeline (<fileObj>, <lineVar>);
  -- functions
  endfile   (<fileObj>) : boolean
  ```
- **ieee.std_logic_textio**
  This package declares more procedures to format `std_logic` values.

  Usage:

  ```
  library ieee;
  use std.textio.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
  ```

  Declarations from `ieee.std_logic_textio`:

  ```
  read   (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,<status>]);            -- binary
  hread  (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,<status>]);            -- hexadecimal
  oread  (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,<status>]);            -- octal
  write  (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,right|left, <width>]); -- binary
  hwrite (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,right|left, <width>]); -- hexadecimal
  owrite (<lineVar>, <vhdlObj> [,right|left, <width>]); -- octal
  ```

Source: [VHDL Kompakt](https://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/doc/ajmMaterial/vhdl.pdf) (German VHDL book from Universität Hamburg)

**Usage example**

The following example writes the value of `mySignal` to a logfile and reports the time.

```
signal mySignal : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
-- ....

process
  file     LogFile    : TEXT open WRITE_MODE is "logfile.log";
  variable LineBuffer : LINE;
begin
  write(LineBuffer,  (     STRING'("========================================")));
  write(LineBuffer,  (CR & STRING'("TESTBENCH REPORT")));
  write(LineBuffer,  (CR & STRING'("========================================")));
  writeline(LogFile, LineBuffer);

  wait until mySignal /= x"00";
  wait until rising_edge(Clock);
  for i in 0 to 7 loop
    wait until rising_edge(Clock);
    write(LineBuffer, "Time " & to_string(now, 1) & "  Value 0x" & raw_format_slv_hex(mySignal));
    writeline(LogFile, LineBuffer);
  end loop;
end process;
```

`now` is a built-in function, representing the current simulation time. It is formatted by [`to_string`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/physical.vhdl#L887-L916), which expects a time and a precision. The signal `mySignal` is formatted by [`raw_format_slv_hex`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L354-L368). This function formats a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` of arbitrary size to a hexadecimal string.

The file should have such content:

```
========================================
TESTBENCH REPORT
========================================
Time 50 ns  Value 0x08
Time 60 ns  Value 0x09
Time 70 ns  Value 0x0A
Time 80 ns  Value 0x0B
Time 90 ns  Value 0x0C
....
```

**One last hint**

`write` procedures append there data to the `LineBuffer` string. When you call writeline, the buffer is written to the file and the `LineBuffer` is empty after that operation.

And finally, here is an [example snippet](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/mem.pkg.vhdl#L113-L149) on how to read a RAM/ROM initialization file and convert it into a generic memory representation.